# Help thinking combinatorics exercise

Tags: combinatorics

Be $m$ parallel straight lines, and in each, $n$ points are chosen.

$a)$ How many subsets of $4$ elements can be chosen with this points?

$b)$ How many of those subsets have as a maximum, two points from each straight line?

What I think is that there are $nm$ points, then, using $ mn \choose 4$ is the answer.

The second one I don't really know how to think it...

Comment: Hint for b): consider the different ways that you can pick 4 points such that there are at most two points from the same line. The only ways are [2,2], [2,1,1], and [1,1,1,1].

Comment: somthing like ${nm \choose 2} {nm - 2 \choose 2} + {nm \choose 2}{nm-2 \choose 1}{nm-3 \choose 1} +{nm \choose 1}{nm-1 \choose 1}{nm-2 \choose 1}{nm-3 \choose 1} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add to your comment because I don't have enough reputation, but I believe that your intuition is wrong for your most recent attempt.

$\binom{nm}2\binom{nm-2}2$ chooses 2 elements from the set and then 2 more elements from the same set of points. you can see that this actually simplifies to $\binom{nm}4$; constraining the solution set should not yield an increase in possible values

Think about how you can alter this equation such that you are limiting lines rather than points

Your most recent attempt:
 $\binom{n}2\binom{m(n-1)}2+\binom{n}1\binom{n}1\binom{m(n-2)}2$
 undercounts the first portion. Fixing the line you are choosing from, you are correct (careful with m's and n's) that you have

$\binom{n}2\binom{n(m-1)}2$. However, you also have $m$ ways to choose the line which you fix $\Rightarrow m\binom{n}2\binom{n(m-1)}2$ *for [2,2] and [2,1,1]*

For the number of ways to choose one line you have $\binom{mn}1\binom{n(m-1)}1\binom{n(m-2)}1\binom{n(m-3)}1 = n^4(m(m-1)(m-2)(m-3))$  *for [1,1,1,1]*

Note that the case in which we select [2, 1, 1] is contained in the first selection. Do you understand why?

Comment: yes, I continued thinking about the exercise, and concluded that what I needed to substract is n elements, and not just 1 element from the set. then ${nm \choose 2} {nm - n \choose 2} + {nm \choose 2}{nm-n \choose 1}{nm-2n \choose 1} +{nm \choose 1}{nm-n \choose 1}{nm-2n \choose 1}{nm-3n \choose 1} $

Comment: think about the first term and what cases it encompasses. is there any case in which it chooses more than 2 elements from the same line? is there something which you are double counting? 

how have you guaranteed that the first two points are selected from the same line?

Comment: $\binom{nm}2 \binom{n(m-1)}2$ says that you're removing one line from the set of parallel lines, but $\binom{nm}2$ can choose points from 2 different lines -- i.e. the case in which you're selecting three points from the same line is present.

Comment: yes, you are right, let me see if I got it clear, first I take 2 elements from a line, and then I take 2 from all the rest... so this is ${n \choose 2} {m(n-1) \choose 2} + {n \choose 1} {n \choose 1} {m(n-2) \choose 2} $

Comment: there was a lot of writing so i appended it to the answer, by the way